# ngIf In angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to display a button if `paymentdone` is due.
Below is my HTML code for Angular using ngIf:

```
<tr>
           <td class="table-id">{{app_list.testbookingmasterid}}</td>
      <td>{{app_list.userid}}</td>
      <td>{{app_list.patientname}}</td>
      <td>{{app_list.paymentdone}} 
        <ng-container *ngIf="{{app_list.paymentdone}}==='due'">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" (click)="demo(app_list.testbookingmasterid,app_list.userid)" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Process</button>
   </ng-container> </td>
      <td>{{app_list.comments}}</td>  
      </tr>
```

But it seems ngIf is not working.

How can I do it? Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: You don't need interpolation `*ngIf="app_list.paymentdone==='due'"`

Comment: No need to use interpolation for `*ngIf` just `*ngIf="app_list.paymentdone==='due'"`

Comment: Thanks.. It worked..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need bracet in an `*ngIf`.

You only have to do =>

```
*ngIf="app_list.paymentdone==='due'"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use interpolation.

Try the following

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(payment==='due')">
          hello payment mode due
</ng-container>
```

**Working Example**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8anxaf

Answer (score 0):

**ngIf** syntax look like this *ngIf="exprestion" , the exprestion can be a check component property if it value truthy or comparison expression like `property === value`

in your case just update the exprestion to this

```
  *ngIf="app_list.paymentdone === 'due'"
```

> not if `app_list` is hasn't initialize or the value will be a result
>   of async operation you need to use '?.' (safe navigation operator) operator so you dont got an
>   error can't read paymentdone  of undefined

final solution look like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="app_list?.paymentdone === 'due' ">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to remove bracet in *ngIf and make it simple

```
*ngIf="app_list.paymentdone==='due'"
```